# How to pass dropdown selected item to PHP file through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The following is the code that displays a dropdown list (database values) I need to send the selected item from dropdown list to another PHP file through JavaScript.

```
<?php include('db.php'); ?>
....
....
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tag').autocomplete("autocomplete.php?",{ seleectFirst: true});
});
</script>
<body>
<select name="province" id="province">
<?php $result=mysql_query("select distinct(type) from schools");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['type'];?>">
 <?php   }?>
</select> 
<input name="tag" type="text" id="tag">
</body></html>
```

I have to pass the item selected in dropdown list to `autocomplete.php` through JavaScript.

Comment: You're doing a *new* assigment that involves using the obsolete `mysql` extension?

Comment: `mysql` isn't secure, use `mysqli`, you would need to pass the connection variable along with it in the first argument, like `mysqli_xxx($dbconx, parameter)` most of the times.

Answer (score -1):

You could probably read the value and call the other PHP link using GET parameters and have the other PHP file read the GET variable. The other method would be to do a POST. An example of the former below...

In a script tag or js file, put this function.

```
function loadPHP() {
    var e = document.getElementById("province");
    var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    location.href = "http://www.website.com/otherphp.php?sel=" + val;
}
```

Trigger it on the onchange event like this...

```
<select name="province" id="province" onchange="loadPHP()">
<?php $result=mysql_query("select distinct(type) from schools");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['type'];?>">
 <?php   }?>
</select>
```